# Not able to access a website in windows azure after publishing. Being redirected

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I created published a web site in Windows azure and I get an address

```
http://xyxmydomain.azurewebsites.net/
```

But when I try to access it I am redirected to www.xyzmydomain.com ...

I have no idea why ... I want to test the site in     http://xyxmydomain.azurewebsites.net/  and I did not configure any domain.com.

Comment: I wonder if u have any redirect on "Page load"

Comment: No ... I have no redirect. This works fine on my computer. It stops working when I publish it

Comment: I just started on my computer and I am not redirected. The moment I updated to Azure I get redirected. It is an MVC application ... No idea why this happens.

Comment: Do you have a custom domain configured for your website?

Comment: No ... Nothing. I did not configure any domain. I just created the website and the SQL server database.

Comment: I wonder what is the behavior when u are trying to publish the default MVC site to Azure (the default template Visual Studio comes with)

Comment: Is just published the default MVC project ... And the result is the same. I am redirected to xyzdomain.com ... Which is even strange as I am using the free account which does not allow to use custom domains. Have no idea what is going on ...